# Gulp: Different Pipe collections within same task (CoffeeScript and JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, npm, gulp

What I've been attempting to do is create one `scripts` task that takes all `.coffee` and `.js` files and does what's needed for each:

- Coffee files should be run through coffee(), coffeelint() and coffeelint.reporter()
- JS files should be run through jshint()
- All files should then be run through concat(), uglify() and ultimately setting a destination as a final build file.

The reason I have some `.coffee` and some `.js` is because I'm using Bower components that have JS files, even though I'd like to init and create my custom scripts with CoffeeScript.

My first pass at this involved [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-if) which allowed me to have every script file in one `gulp.src()` declaration -- piping through to a the appopriate check on the extension (using gulp-if) and doing the necessary actions there. Oddly enough, that didn't pan out; kept failing saying there was a stream error; saying there was an issue with gulp-uglify(), but I could never decipher what the actual issue was -- with my gulp file or with what gulp-if said could be an issue with how a specific plugin was built. So, I then though having two different streams and then running them at the same time could work (see what I had for this so far) but then I'd be left with two completely separate builds -- which I could obviously concat after the fact, but I'm left with ugly temp files and the inability to mix in `.coffee` and `.js` files if they need to be done in a certain order.

Ideally I'd like to be able to mix my src files within whatever extension I want, call the necessary actions depending on the extension and pass through to the other items that both share. I'd appreciate any input. Thanks!

What I had so far (described above):

```
// Load plugins
var gulp              = require('gulp'),
    jshint            = require('gulp-jshint'),
    coffee            = require('gulp-coffee'),
    changed           = require('gulp-changed'),
    coffeelint        = require('gulp-coffeelint'),
    gulpif            = require('gulp-if'),
    uglify            = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sourcemaps        = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    notify            = require('gulp-notify'),
    concat            = require('gulp-concat'),
    filesize          = require('gulp-size'),
    livereload        = require('gulp-livereload'),
    duration          = require('gulp-duration'),
    gutil             = require('gulp-util'),
    merge = require('merge-stream'),
    es         = require('event-stream');

gulp.task('test', function() {
  var jsBuildDir = 'assets/js/build/';

  var coffeescript =
    gulp.src([
      'assets/js/src/_init.coffee'
    ])
    .pipe(coffee())
    .pipe(coffeelint())
    .pipe(coffeelint.reporter())
    .pipe(concat('coffee.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(filesize({
      title: 'CoffeeScript:'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsBuildDir))
    .pipe(duration('building coffeescript files'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Coffeescript task complete' }));

  var js =
    gulp.src([
      'assets/js/src/_init.js'
    ])
    .pipe(jshint({
          'boss': true,
          'sub': true,
          'evil': true,
          'browser': true,
          'globals': {
            'module': false,
            'require': true
          }
       }),
      jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(concat('js.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsBuildDir))
    .pipe(filesize({
      title: 'Main Scripts:'
    }))
    .pipe(duration('building main JS files'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Main scripts task complete' }));

    es.concat(cofeescript, js);

});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  gulp.watch(['assets/js/src/**/*.js', 'assets/js/src/**/*.coffee'], ['hint-n-lint', 'scripts']);

  // Create LiveReload server
  var server = livereload();

  // Watch files in patterns below, reload on change
  gulp.watch(['assets/js/build/*']).on('change', function(file) {
    server.changed(file.path);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in a 2 tasks row:

1. Process coffee files (eg: transform them to javascript)
2. Process javascript files that will wait for the coffee task to proceed before starting

My `gulpfile.js` would be:

```
var coffee_files = ['assets/js/src/*.coffee']
var js_files = ['assets/js/src/*.js']

gulp.task('coffee', function() {
    //note the return is very important here
    return gulp.src(coffee_files)
        .pipe(coffee()) //do your pipes
        //dest to the same folder assuming those are now js files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/src')) 
})

gulp.task('javascript', ['coffee'], function() {
    return gulp.src(js_files)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/build'))
})

/**
* Now, `gulp` command will first process coffee files, transform them to javascript
* then javascript is executed and minifies stuff to your destination folder
*/
gulp.task('default', ['javascript'])

/**
* `gulp coffee` will only process coffee files
* `gulp javascript` will only process javascript files
* Watching files can be done like this:
*/
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(coffee_files, ['javascript'])
    gulp.watch(js_files, ['javascript'])
})
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer! I think this is a great first step because it solves the issue of a "leftover" file in the dest/ directory, but what this still doesn't go after is bunching CoffeeScript files separately from JS ones; throwing any order constraints out the window. Would love if I could have all of my "scripts" together `gulp.src(['library.js', 'init.coffee'])` and have gulp figure out what to do from there with each type of file.

Comment: That's not the best way of doing this because you have **specific tasks** for `coffee` that differs from pure `js` so, those **tasks** should be separated. The best way I can think of is to move coffee files to a specifi directory, process javascript and then concat all the files in a third task.

Comment: Thanks - agree that I should use the "just because you can doesn't mean you should" rule and separate these things out into more focused parts.