# Pass .js files through gulp-typescript without ERROR TS6054

Tags: typescript, gulp

I want to include typescript in my main gulp tool chain, so that I can convert .js files to .ts files as-needed and as time permits. It's fine if the typescript step performs no action on .js files.

Does that make sense? If so, how can I accomplish this? I tried the following:

```
function compileScript(inputFiles, outputName, outputPath) {
    return r.gulp.src(inputFiles)
        .pipe(r.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(r.ngAnnotate())
// I'd like to do this, but processing fails if not all files are *.ts
//      .pipe(r.typescript({ target: 'ES5' }))
        .pipe(r.uglify())
        .pipe(r.concat(outputName))
        .pipe(r.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(r.gulp.dest(outputPath));
}
```

But it produces no output, citing:

> ERROR 6054: File 'script.js' must have extension '.ts' or '.d.ts'.

Perhaps there is a typescript option that I've overlooked, or a gulp conditional pipe tool that won't break my sourcemaps? If I run two separate steps of .ts and .js files, they will end up concatenated out-of-order.

I'd like to avoid a big-bang approach.

p.s. I'm building an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're currently providing full list of files to `gulp-typescript`, filter out only `*.ts` ones using [`gulp-filter`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter):

```
function compileScript(inputFiles, outputName, outputPath) {
    var filter = require('gulp-filter')('**/*.ts'); // setup filter

    return r.gulp.src(inputFiles)
        .pipe(r.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(filter) // filter out *.ts files
        .pipe(r.typescript({ target: 'ES5' })) // compile them
        .pipe(filter.restore()) // restore all other files to proceed
        .pipe(r.ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(r.uglify())
        .pipe(r.concat(outputName))
        .pipe(r.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(r.gulp.dest(outputPath));
}
```

As a side note, I think you should first compile `*.ts` files and only after that `ng-annotate` them.

Comment: looks awesome. question, do you know offhand if sourcemap pointers will be incorrect from this 'mutation'?

Comment: TypeScript compiler can emit source maps with the code if needed. If you're going to have 2 passes on the code (first TypeScript, then ng-annotate), and have source map point correctly to your `*.ts` files, I never tried that. Try asking it as a new question on SO, someone should be able to help.

Comment: I appreciate the help, and am certainly not complaining. What I'm concerned about is that "gulp-filter" (suggested in your solution) may break sourcemaps, a necessary part of my toolchain. I do not see 'gulp-filter' among the 30-40 plugins with sourcemap support, sadly. I'll try it out and accept this solution if it works properly. Otherwise there may still be solutions, and if I can find a solution that includes yours as a component I'll also accept. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045370/gulp-filter-with-sourcemaps

Comment: `gulp-filter` does not affect sourcemaps, it just filters out part of the files and restores them later. What may (perhaps) break your source maps, however, is the fact that there are 2 source code conversions: first with `tsc`, thatn with `ng-annotate`.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue to the best of my knowledge, if I understand what you are describing. I don't know where the mapping state is held from one pipe to the next, but what you are describing already occurs with ngAnnotate, ulglify, and concat, and the map generates smoothly. It must hold relative references through each stage, which could easily be defeated by the filter misrepresenting the input stream to typescript, without corrective offsets. At any rate, I'm in the process of trying out a .ts file now.